# How to use linebreak in read -p command while using variables in prompt string

Tags: shell, user-input

I want to have a line break after prompt while using the cowsay function in the prompt :

```
read -p "$(cowsay "do you know this word?") \n" answer
```

there are multiple answers to this problem :

1)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296108/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-for-read-command/4296147

2)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741529/how-to-break-a-line-add-a-newline-in-read-p-in-bash

However the answers use the `''` notation, which doesn't resolve the `cowsay` command

Comment: Something like this? `cowsay "do you know this word?" ; read answer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use the `-p` option for which you'd need the `bash` shell?

Just do:

```
cowsay "do you know this word?"
read answer
```

In `bash`, the `-p` option is only useful in conjunction with `-e` (another `bash` extension which makes `bash`'s `read` behave like `zsh`'s `vared`) where `bash` may need to redraw the prompt on some occasions (like upon <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>). But then, you would probably not need nor want it to redraw that prompt when it's several lines.

If you wanted to, you could always do:

```
read -ep "$(cowsay "do you know this word?")"$'\n' answer
```

(here using ksh93's `$'...'` form of quoting that understands C-like escape sequences)

or

```
read -ep "$(cowsay "do you know this word?")
" answer
```

More generally, the problem is that command substitution strips newline characters (not just one, all of them which could be considered a bug/misfeature¹) from the end of the command's output.

To work around that, the usual trick is to do:

```
output=$(cowsay "do you know this word?"; echo .)
output=${output%.}
read -p "$output" answer
```

That is, add `.\n` to the output. Command substitution strips  the `\n` and we strip the `.` with `${output%.}` leaving the whole command's output (provided it doesn't contain NUL characters in shells other than `zsh`, and that it's valid text in the current locale in `yash`).

For the record, in other Korn-like shells, the syntax for `read` to issue a prompt by itself is with:

```
read 'answer?prompt: '
```

The Korn shell would also redraw that prompt when reading from the terminal and an editor option has been enabled (like with `set -o emacs` or `set -o vi`). `zsh` also supports that syntax for compatibility, but the line editor is only used for `vared`, not for `read` there.

---

<sup>¹ for instance, it makes things like `basename=$(basename -- "$file")` wrong, as it could strip newline characters from the end of the file name, not just the one added by `basename`</sup>